# How to Bind MVC DropBox With Sql Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private readonly List<IceCreamFlavor> _flavors;

    [Display(Name = "Favorite Flavor")]
    public int SelectedFlavorId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FlavorItems
    {
        get { return new SelectList(_flavors, "Id", "Name");}
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far?

Comment: i would be grateful if you could explain me it in step by step.Still i have only  query for read data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it's like this:

- Provide a) A value property in the model, and b) A collection to hold your possible items
- Fill the collection with "some" data
- Add the control to the page

So, in your controller:

```
var model = new ViewModel();
model.FlavorItems = new IceCreamFlavor[] {
    new IceCreamFlavor(1, "Vanilla"),
    new IceCreamFlavor(2, "Chocolate")
};
```

And in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedFlavorId, new SelectList(Model.FlavorItems, "Id", "Name"))
```